# Python: if date is passed or not logic with strings

Tags: python, date

In a large program that iterates over many many dates, I'm trying to process only dates that are passed (or at) a `cutoff_date` where `date >= cutoff_date`. This works great 99% of the time, however check out the following:

```
>>> print cutoff_date, type(cutoff_date)
2015-2-19 <type 'str'>
>>> a = '2015-3-20'
>>> a >= cutoff_date
True
>>> b = '2015-1-2'
>>> b >= cutoff_date
False
>>> c = '2015-2-9'
>>> c >= cutoff_date
True                     # I need this to be False ...
>>> d = '2015-2-09'
>>> d >= cutoff_date
False                    # ... just like this
>>>
```

I know that I could set up a function where if the day of a date is one digit, add a `0` to the front of it. However I fear that this could screw up the rest of my code. Therefore before I go doing so, I'm wondering if threre is an easier way to solve this?

Comment: That's because you're not processing dates, you're processing strings. Those are handled alphabetically by default.

Comment: Parse the dates using `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date` and you should be good to go. Something like `datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d")` might be good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) module to work with dates, and [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to parse strings that represent dates.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> cutoff = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-2-19', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> a = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-3-20', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> b = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-1-2', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> c = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-2-9', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-2-09', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> a>=cutoff
True
>>> b>=cutoff
False
>>> c>=cutoff
False
>>> d>=cutoff
False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dateify = lambda ds: datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> dateify('2015-2-19') > dateify('2015-2-18')
True
>>> dateify('2015-2-19') > dateify('2015-2-20')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare dates properly you have to make them `DateTime` or `Date` objects. To do that use `datetime.datetime.strptime()`:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('2015-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
cut_off = datetime(2015, 9, 1)
if d >= cutoff:
    print('True')
```